# Use renderUI to insert additional tabPanel in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

I am trying to append a tab created by renderUI to an existing tab set. Minimal example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),
                              mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                                tabPanel("static_tab"),
                                uiOutput('ui_tab')
                              ))))
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ui_tab <- renderUI({
    tabPanel("render_tab", p('it worked'))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I can get an an entire tabsetPanel to render, but not an individual tab in an existing tabsetPanel.

Comment: if you can render a `tabset` dynamically why not just rerender the whole `tabset`? because I think it's impossible to achieve what you want the way you want to do it

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk it's absolutely possible, but `renderUI` won't work in this case (see below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `insertTab` or `appendTab`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),
                              mainPanel(
                                tabsetPanel(id = "myTabsetPanel",
                                            tabPanel("static_tab", tabName = "static_tab"))
                              )))
server <- function(input, output) {
  appendTab(inputId = "myTabsetPanel",
            tabPanel("render_tab", p('it worked')))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`renderUI` won't work as it creates a `div` tag - however, you need to create a `li` tag.

Comment: clean solution.